Why Pytorch is much slower than Python dictionary?
I'm a new student in machine learning, currently learning about Pytorch. It is mentioned that running Pytorch tensors in GPU is much faster than running any array/tensor/dictionary in CPU. I have the following code for Q-learning using OpenAI's frozen lake environment which I wrote using python dictionary operations:
import gymnasium as gym
import numpy as np

# Q-learning: Off-policy TD control
def Q_learning(env, alpha, gamma, epsilon, episodes):
    states = list(range(env.observation_space.n))
    actions = list(range(env.action_space.n))
    Q = {s:{a:0 for a in actions} for s in states}
    Pi = {s:0 for s in states}
    V = {s:0 for s in states}
    V_eps = {} # For storing the episode values
    for ep in range(episodes):
        S, _ = env.reset()
        done = False
        while not done:
            if np.random.random() < epsilon: # epsilon-greedy policy
                A = np.random.choice(actions)
            else:
                A = max(Q[S], key=Q[S].get)
            Sp, R, done, _, _ = env.step(A)
            Q[S][A] += alpha * (R + (gamma * max(Q[Sp].values())) - Q[S][A])           
            S = Sp
        for s in states:
            V[s] = max(Q[s].values())
            Pi[s] = max(Q[s], key=Q[s].get)
        V_eps[ep] = V.copy() # storing the episoding values
        if ep%10000==0:
            print(f"episode {ep} Finished!", end='\r')    
    Vm = np.reshape(list(V.values()), (8,8))
    Pim = np.reshape(list(Pi.values()), (8,8))
    print("Value from Q-learning,\n", Vm)
    print("Policy from Q-learning,\n", Pim)
    return V, Q, V_eps, Pim

# Make the environment
env = gym.make('FrozenLake-v1', desc=None, map_name="8x8", is_slippery = True)
V, Q, V_eps_Q, Pim = Q_learning(env=env, alpha=0.9, gamma=0.95, epsilon=0.9, episodes=100000)
env.close()

Running this code for 100000 episodes took 1 minute 9 seconds in my computer. Then I installed pytorch and make sure that CUDA is enabled (I have Nvidia RTX 3060 Laptop GPU).
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()

This outputs "True" in the console. Now I converted all the python dictionaries into tensors, sent it to CUDA, and updated the following code:
import gymnasium as gym
import numpy as np

# Q-learning: Off-policy TD control
def Q_learning(env, alpha, gamma, epsilon, episodes):
    states = torch.arange(env.observation_space.n).to(device="cuda")
    actions = torch.arange(env.action_space.n).to(device="cuda")
    Q = torch.zeros((env.observation_space.n, env.action_space.n)).to(device="cuda")
    Pi = torch.zeros((env.observation_space.n)).to(device="cuda")
    V = torch.zeros((env.observation_space.n)).to(device="cuda")
    V_eps = torch.zeros((episodes, env.observation_space.n)).to(device="cuda") # for storing the episode values
    for ep in range(episodes):
        S, _ = env.reset()
        while True:
            if np.random.random() < epsilon: # epsilon-greedy policy
                A = np.random.randint(4)
            else:
                A = torch.argmax(Q[S])
            A = int(A)
            Sp, R, done, _, _ = env.step(A)
            Q[S,A] += alpha * (R + (gamma * torch.max(Q[Sp])) - Q[S,A])
            S = Sp
            if done:
                break
        for s in states:
            V[s] = torch.max(Q[s])
            Pi[s] = torch.argmax(Q[s])
        if ep%1000==0:
            print(f"episode {ep}/{episodes} Finished!", end='\r')
        V_eps[ep] = V.detach().clone()
    print("Value from Q-learning,\n", V)
    print("Policy from Q-learning,\n", Pi)
    return V, Q, V_eps, Pi

# Make the environment
env = gym.make('FrozenLake-v1', desc=None, map_name="8x8", is_slippery = True)
V, Q, V_eps_Q, Pi = Q_learning(env=env, alpha=0.9, gamma=0.95, epsilon=0.9, episodes=100000)
env.close()

But now it is sooo much slower than my previous code (Only 20,000 episodes in 10 minute!). I expected it to be faster. What is happening in here?? Is Pytorch slower than Python dictionary which is running in CPU? Or Pytorch is ONLY faster for neural networks, and not tensor operations?

CUDA is fast because it supports massive parallelism, meaning that if a and b are large-scale tensors, c=a+b will be a lot faster than for i in len(a): c[i]=a[i]+b[i] because individual elements can be summed in parallel. However, there is not much vectorized arithmetics in your code, so there is apparent performance improvement.

Well I thought "Q[S,A] += alpha * (R + (gamma * torch.max(Q[Sp])) - Q[S,A])" would do parallel operations since they are all tensor operations. Even in this case, it should be AT LEAST AS FAST AS python dict right? @ihdv Just tell me one thing: If I run a for loop in python dictionary (no parallel operation), and a for loop in Pytorch tensors (no parallel), does it mean that tensor operations will be SLOWER?

What are S, A, Sp exactly? Are they  tensors or ints? If tensors, what are their shapes?

They are integers @ihdv

That's it then, these are not vectorized operations (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vectorized-operations-in-numpy/). Unlike c++, indexing with integers in python is really slow. So you should change your algorithm to using vectorized operations as much as possible.

Regarding the "at least as fast as python dict" part, I would say not necessarily. This is because: (1) you have an overhead moving data between CPU and GPU, which does not exist if you use only python dict; (2) GPU is only fast because it has a lot of threads. Without parallel tasks to run, GPUs are not necessarily faster.

@ihdv how can I send the index of a tensor as a vector? Isn't the index always an integer? Is it ever possible to be the index to something else? I'm a bit confused because even in a tensor x of length 2, I always call x[0] to get the first element. Should I use x[0.0] instead? Or something like x[tensor([0])]?

You might get good optimisations on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

is it permissible to post same thing on another stackexchange? @BramVanroy
